# CoCreateInstance returning "REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG Class not registered"

Tags: windows, class, object, com, return

Recently, I am working on programming with COM object. The code is as follows.

```
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    HRESULT hr = NULL;  
    CLSID clsid;
    LPOLESTR pProgID;
    LPCOLESTR lpsz = L"{417976B7-917D-4F1E-8F14-C18FCCB0B3A8}"; 
    hr = CLSIDFromString(lpsz, &clsid);
    
    hr = ProgIDFromCLSID(clsid, &pProgID);
    IUnknown *pUnknown;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_ENABLE_CLOAKING, IID_IUnknown, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pUnknown));  
    CoUninitialize();
```

I have got a problem when I call CoCreateInstance with CLSCTX_ENABLE_CLOAKING. It fails and I've got a error "REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG Class not registered". If anyone know solution, please inform me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `CLSCTX_ALL | CLSCTX_ENABLE_CLOAKING`

Comment: Oh, it works. Thank you very much. Would you give more explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the current doc is not clear about these flags, when you use [CoCreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cocreateinstance#remarks), you *must* specify the type of server used to manage the object, so COM can activate it (it's usually about inprocess vs out of process). [Other flags such as CLSCTX_ENABLE_CLOAKING  are optional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtypesbase/ne-wtypesbase-clsctx).

> The constants can be CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, CLSCTX_INPROC_HANDLER,
> CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, CLSCTX_REMOTE_SERVER or any combination of these
> values. The constant CLSCTX_ALL is defined as the combination of all
> four.

CLSCTX_ALL means "I don't care whether it's inprocess, out-of-process, remote, etc.", but activate it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was a great help.